# formatting HTML paragraphs with CSS 

Tags: html, css, web, formatting

I want to be able to highlight the text (paragraph) without it going across the entire page. Can someone help me confine this paragraph?

here is a link to a screen shot image showing the problem i am having: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/print1xs.png/

Heres my HTML code:

```
    <div id="content">

    <p> I like to play with pokemon <br>
        They are a fun way to relax
    <br>
        Go pokemon. 
    </p>
    </div>
```

Heres my CSS:

```
    #content{
    margin: 200px 0 0 73px;
    }

    #content p{
    font-size: 2em;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that your div is actually that large. Add a wrapper (or just constrain the width of #content) and set the width to however wide your content is, and the highlight will remain in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#content p{
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: magenta;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! that was an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following tag at the beginning of the highlighted text: `<span style="background color: #FFFF99">`. You can use any color you want, though this text highlights it in light yellow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "highlight" the whole paragraph, set a background color for the paragraph. Also, to keep it from stretching the whole way across your div just change the paragraph width, like so:

.highlighted{background-color: #ffff00; width: 100px;}